# Google.Apis.Calendar.v3.dll ask 1.9.2 version on Google APIs

Tags: c#, google-calendar-api, google-api-dotnet-client

I setup nuget packages

```
Install-Package Google.Apis.Core
Install-Package Google.Apis
Install-Package Google.Apis.Auth
```

As it said there http://google-api-dotnet-client.blogspot.ca/
*We have released a 1.9.3 version of NuGet packages only for the Core packages - that’s where the new features are. You should still use 1.9.2 version of the API specific packages (such as Drive) and only update the Core packages*

```
Install-Package Google.Apis.Calendar.v3
```

When I tried to build it I'm getting error:

```
    Assuming assembly reference 'Google.Apis, Version=1.9.2.27817, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=4b01fa6e34db77ab' matches 'Google.Apis, Version=1.9.3.19379, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=4b01fa6e34db77ab', 
you may need to supply runtime policy
```

I added redirect script in web.config:

```
<dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Google.Apis" publicKeyToken="4b01fa6e34db77ab"/>
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.9.2.27817" newVersion="1.9.3.19379" />
    </dependentAssembly>
```

but still getting the same error. I check it with spy and it appears Calendar dll wants old API.

Any idea how to fix it? (Thanks)

Comment: I think as mentioned here http://google-api-dotnet-client.blogspot.ca/ , you should only update the core packages and should still be on version 1.9.2 not 1.9.3

Comment: Thank you for trying help - unfortunately this v3 dll is 1.9.2 version.
But I found workaround for me - I delete all google apis and install package for calendar library - it installed all apis library it needs (1.9.2 versions)